# unable to enumerate USB device : USB

Tags: usb

My device is not able to detect a USB Camera , I checked, `uvcvideo` module and it's already inserted.

```
    Module                  Size  Used by
    uvcvideo               73728  0
    videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
    videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
    usb_f_ecm              16384  1
    g_ether                16384  0
    usb_f_rndis            20480  2 g_ether
    u_ether                20480  3 usb_f_ecm,usb_f_rndis,g_ether
    libcomposite           45056  3 usb_f_ecm,usb_f_rndis,g_ether
    arc4                   16384  2
    wl18xx                 73728  0
    wlcore                159744  1 wl18xx
    mac80211              323584  2 wl18xx,wlcore
    cfg80211              221184  3 mac80211,wl18xx,wlcore
    mxc_v4l2_capture       36864  0
    ipu_bg_overlay_sdc     16384  1 mxc_v4l2_capture
    ipu_still              16384  1 mxc_v4l2_capture
    ipu_prp_enc            16384  1 mxc_v4l2_capture
    ipu_csi_enc            16384  1 mxc_v4l2_capture
    ipu_fg_overlay_sdc     16384  1 mxc_v4l2_capture
    v4l2_int_device        16384  1 mxc_v4l2_capture
    wlcore_sdio            16384  0
    galcore               217088  0
    gpio_keys              20480  0
```

```
    dmesg 
    usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 78 using ci_hdrc
    usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
    usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 79 using ci_hdrc
    usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
    usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 80 using ci_hdrc
    usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
    usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
    usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 81 using ci_hdrc
    usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
    usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
    usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

If any additional info required. Comment please.

Any Help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: version/distro of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

Start with inspecting what those error numbers stand for ... The easiest way is to install [`moreutils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/moreutils) like so:

```bash
sudo apt install moreutils
```

Then use [`errno`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/errno.1.html) to look them up like so:

```bash
$ errno 71
EPROTO 71 Protocol error
```

Then do your research troubleshooting, and logic.

If I had to throw a guess, I would say the problem is either of:

1. A broken/damaged USB port.
2. A broken/damaged USB cable.
3. A corrupted driver/libraries.
4. A broken/damaged USB device.

And in that order.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I'm using a non-powered USB expansion device on one of my front ports. I started unplugging devices lo and behold it was the Android phone I had plugged in last night that was causing the issue. It was locked up/frozen. As soon as I unplugged it and replugged it in my other devices all worked again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1295857)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue trying to flash an old android phone with Micro-B connector.
The problem was in the cables, 2 of 3 cable i used were not ok.
The third cable worked.